# create come back condition on camunda

Tags: conditional-statements, business-process-management, camunda-modeler

I need to create a condition for my camunada when I come back.

[image]

the goal is :

1. I validate the phone number and come back, I must be on the screen where I must enter the mail address and the mobil number.
2. I don't validate the phone number and come back, I must be on the screen where I can validate my phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modelling a business process. This process has a persistent state. So whenever the process reached a user task, until you complete it, the process will wait at that user task. 
This does not depend on you coming back.